# $http.get on HoverOver to populate PopOver text

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, model-view-controller

I'm trying to implement a feature using Angular and Boostrap where the user can get a popOver on an item in the list, and have it perform an angular factory $http.get function to retrieve data and populate the popover text.

I'm not sure this is the best approach, but I have a ng-repeat like so:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="product in products">
        <model-popover ng-attr-id="{{product.Id}}"></model-popover>                            
    </li>
</ul>
```

And my best guess is to use an angular directive, taking in the id number as a scope attribute,and performing a factory call from the directive.  I've read up on the controller/link functions within the directive, but not sure the proper implementation

```
app.directive('modelPopover', ['Factory', function (Factory) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            scope: { id: "=" },
            controller: function($scope){
                var prod = Factory.getProductDetail(id);
            },
            template: '<a popover-placement="bottom" popover="{{prod}}">{{prod}}</a> '
        };
    }]);
```

I know the directive is incorrect, but i'm hoping there's enough information to help me out.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You do not need special directive for this, due to value-binding u can just change scope variable and popover will change also.
So u simply:

```
  <button popover="{{var}}" popover-trigger="mouseenter" class="btn btn-default" ng-mouseover="changeVar()">Mouseenter</button>
```

And in changeVar you can change $scope.var any way you want.
Here is example plunk ($http call emulated using $timeout):
http://plnkr.co/edit/gnm1BtnHzNLnvO62Ar2i?p=preview

Comment: Haven't had time to try it yet, but I'll try it when i get a chance! Thanks!

Comment: I noticed when trying it your way is that the hoverover does not populate with data the first time.  It shows "?"

Comment: it emulates real situation, when u hover - there is no data yet, so u show smth like 'loading...' or waiting image. In this example ? is shown, 2 sec later it is replaced with data.

Comment: so would I need to add some sort of watch statement? The popover does not update until i re-hover over the button.

Comment: hmm, my plunk dont work for u? just checked in ie11 and chrome - work as expected

Comment: Didn't really work, but maybe because my workplace is stuck on IE9?

Answer (score 1):

This `var prod = Factory.getProductDetail(id);`
has to be changed to `$scope.prod = Factory.getProductDetail(id)` if you want to use the mustaches